# Google's Native Client - make error arc4random could not be located in cygwin1.dll

Tags: google-nativeclient

I have followed the tutorial by google: https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1. In the second step when I try to `make serve` I get the following error: **clang.exe - The procedure entry point arc4random could not be located in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll.**

I am using the stable version *pepper_31* on Windows 7 64 Bit with Chrome Dev Channel Ver 33.0.1707.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running make from the cygwin terminal or from windows cmd.exe?

Comment: Hi @Derek I am running from windows cmd.exe